# Empty Value does not return

Tags: powershell, vsphere

```
Get-VM |
    Select Name, Operatingsystem, VMHost, PowerState,
        @{N="Datastore"; E={$_ |
            Get-Datastore}} |
    Out-gridview
```

I ran this command. It will return and output a grid view with all rows filled in.

However, the field "OperatingSystem" returns a blank column, nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think you can do this:

```
Get-VM | Select-Object Name, 
                       @{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; Expression = {$_.Guest.OsFullName}},
                       VMHost, PowerState,
                       @{Name = 'Datastore'; Expression = {$_ | Get-Datastore}} |
         Out-GridView
```

Comment: Theo, you can add that to the list of tested PowerShell scripts as it worked flawless it output the field: Name, Operating System, VMHost/IP, PowerState, Datastore. Now on to testing if I can output the list into a csv/excel form. Great work.

Comment: @Rbuckle Thanks for confirming!. To output to CSV is easy: just replace `Out-GridView` with `Export-Csv -Path 'X:\VMInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation`. You can add `-UseCulture` if you like to ensure the delimiter used in the file is what your locally installed Excel would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "Guest" property I think. FYI you can also do this to view everything if you're not sure of the exact name

```
Get-VM |
Select-Object -Property * |
Out-gridview
```